# В чем ошибка в поиске k-ой порядковой статистики?

Tags: java

*На вход подается A[0] и A[1].
Далее строится последовательность вида*:

```java
for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
    A[i] = (A[i - 1] * 123 + A[i - 2] * 45) % (10000000 + 4321);
}
```

В этой последовательности необходимо найти К-ую порядковую статистику. Я реализую метод `QuickSelect`:

```java
public static int QuickSelect(int[] A, int l, int r, int k) {
    int wall = Partition(A, l, r);
    if (r - l + 1 < 2) {
        return A[k];
    } else {
        if (k < wall) {
            return QuickSelect(A, l, wall - 1, k);
        } else {
            return QuickSelect(A, wall, r, k);
        }
    }
}
```

В данном методе `Partition` у меня выглядит так:

```java
public static int Partition(int[] A, int l, int r) {
    int x = (int) (Math.random() * (r - l + 1) + l);
    int min = A[l];
    for (int i = l; i <= r; i++) {
        if (A[i] < min) {
            min = A[i];
        }
    }
    int max = A[l];
    for (int i = l; i <= r; i++) {
        if (A[i] > max) {
            max = A[i];
        }
    }
    int pivot = A[x];
    if (min == max) {
        return (l + r)/2;
    } else {
        if (A[x] == min) {
            pivot = pivot + 1;
        }
        if (A[x] == max) {
            pivot = pivot - 1;
        }
    }
    int C = l - 1;
    for (int i = l; i <= r; i++) {
        int y = A[i];
        if (y < A[x]) {
            int fake = A[C + 1];
            A[C + 1] = A[i];
            A[i] = fake;
            ++C;
        }
    }
    return C + 1;
}
```

Я вывожу это:

```java
System.out.println(QuickSelect(A, 0, n - 1, k - 1));
```

Указание:
На вход подается n, k, A[0], A[1] (n - количество элементов в последовательности, k - номер порядковой статистики).
На легких тестах программа работает верно:

- для `10 5 1 2` выводит `321287`.
- для `2 2 100 1000` выводит `1000`.

Случай с первым и вторым элементом `0 0` я проверяю отдельно.

Однако при таком вводе: `100 50 1 2` на выводе, запуская пару раз, получаю разные ответы.
Например, `5241498, 4780903` (правильный), `4671533`.
Правильным ответом в таком случае является `4780903`.
В чем состоит ошибка?

Comment: А как вы определили правильный. В чем идея Partition метода?

Comment: Он правильный, т.к человек, который решил задачу, проверил на вводе: 100 50 1 2, и получил 4780903.
Partition - метод для разделения массива на две части: слева элементы, меньшие случайного х из массива, справа больше или равные случайного элемента.

Comment: Вы намеренно не смотрите 1 элемент он же А[0]  когда перебираете массив в Partition?

Comment: В каком методе идет перебор массива, скажите точнее

Comment: int min = A[l];
    for (int i = l; i..

Comment: Извините, вы так неудачно выбрали переменные что путаю где 1 а где l

Comment: Там всё норм, изначально l = 0;
А переменные т.к left и right.

Comment: Не понятно использование переменной pivot?

Comment: Так для порядковой статистики результат должен быть один, в независимости от выбранного pivot.

Comment: Эт понятно. Только вот удалить весь кусок. else {
        if (A[x] == min) {
            pivot = pivot + 1;
        }
        if (A[x] == max) {
            pivot = pivot - 1;
        }
   Ничего не поменяет

Comment: Хорошо. А ошибка то в чем может быть, почему результаты разные?

Comment: Может быть с wall что-то не так, или с границами рекурсии?

Comment: Ну тут как говорится без пол литра не поймёшь :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже, ошибка в том, что `pivot` вычисляется, но не используется в цикле, где выполняется перестановка элементов.

Если в методе `Partition` заменить условие `if (y < A[X])` на `if (y < pivot)`, то результаты "стабилизируются" и для ввода `100 50 1 2` будет возвращаться `4780903`.

Также `min`, `max` можно определить в одном и том же цикле.

```java
public static int Partition(int[] A, int l, int r) {
    int min = A[l], max = A[l];
    for (int i = l + 1; i <= r; i++) {
        if (A[i] < min) {
            min = A[i];
        } else if (A[i] > max) {
            max = A[i];
        }
    }
    if (min == max) {
        return (l + r)/2;
    }

    int x = (int) (Math.random() * (r - l + 1) + l);
    int pivot = A[x];
    if (pivot == min) {
        pivot += 1;
    } else if (pivot == max) {
        pivot -= 1;
    }
    
    int C = l - 1;
    for (int i = l; i <= r; i++) {
        if (A[i] < pivot) {
            int fake = A[C + 1];
            A[C + 1] = A[i];
            A[i] = fake;
            ++C;
        }
    }
    return C + 1;
}
```